# Get a Graph item image changing onTouch - Android

Tags: java, android, gridview, ontouch

I am trying to get an individual item within a `GridView` to change image when a finger moves across it. I have two images, `no_touch` and `touch`. What I want is for all of the items in GridView to be set as no_touch when the activity is started, and when any one or more of the items is touched by finger just those ones change to the `touch` image.

All I can get so far is when one of the items is **clicked** it changes the background of the **whole** GridView (and a small toast appears). I want to be able to "glide" along each item and have only those ones change image.

My code so far:

*MainActivity.java*:

```
public class MainActivty extends Activity {

 drawingView dview;
 GridView grid;

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_activity1);

    final GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
    gridview.setVisibility(GridView.VISIBLE);

    gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                int position, long id) {
            gridview.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            Toast.makeText(Activity1.this, "Position " + position,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
  }
}
```

*ImageAdapter.java*

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context mContext;

public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
    mContext = c;
    }

public int getCount() {
    return mThumbIds.length;
    }

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
    }

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
    }

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView;
    if (convertView == null) {
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }
    imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
    return imageView;
}

public Integer[] mThumbIds = {R.drawable.images ....};
}
```

If anyone knows how to, even just to get an individual item changing image onClick, it would be brilliant.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

You've set the click listener on the grid. To do what you are expecting (clicking on the itens) you should set the listener on each ImageView that you have on this GridView.

Example:

```
imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {...});
```

If you know the size and the images that you have, a better approach would be via XML layout and drawables using the  itens with the status "pressed" and default.

```
<selector
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/thedrawable_whenpressed">
    </item>

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/the_default_drawable">
    </item>
</selector>
```

Comment: I tried implementing the xml version but the app crashes. The java version would probably be easier to implement long term if I want to change click to touch. I tried changing around my code from gridview to imageView but with all the changing around in the code it got confusing. Thanks for the methods though. I may still get them working sometime